# I screw up the database and schema of my rails app, what should I do to rebuild database from my migration files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, reset

My code is all OK, and it has all and only the migrations from which I want my database to be create, as I re-run them one bye one..

How should I do this.

my schema file is also screwed up.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your schema file is wrong you can drop your database with `rake db:drop`, then recreate it with `rake db:create` and finally run simple `rake db:migrate` to run all migrations you have (assuming that you have only migrations you want to run, i.e. you deleted others).

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake db:reset` inside your rails root directory.